gopls: failed to install gopls(golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest):Error:Command failed: /usr/local/go/bin/go install -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest
The go package is installed and go extension is also installed but in my linux it is failing that can be seen in output tab of VScode
Tried reinstalling go extension and the go lang again after uninstalling it still not working
